# Win32API - How to determine which file is being held by which process?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32-process

Currently, in my source code, I have used [rename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to change file name. But it is failed, i think this file that is hold by another thread or process or program.
So, could you help me to determine this file is being held by which process ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with SysInternals' Process Explorer and Handle utilities?  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/

Comment: for rename file - use `CreateFile(..DELETE.. OPEN_EXISTING)` + `SetFileInformationByHandle`. and what is error if fail ?

Comment: [How do I find out which process has a file open?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120217-00/?p=8283)

Comment: rename() is not normally a problem, as long as you don't rename across disk drives.  Processes can only lock the file content, not the directory entry.  But anti-malware is never not a problem, so try again with it disabled to see what that does.